# want to send email with attachment on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Actually I am novice on ruby on rails. And I want to send email with attachment like pdf or excel file on rails 4 but I did not get any exact solution for it. so tell me the solution for it.

Comment: maybe this? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_sending_email.htm

Comment: it's easier for people to help you if they have some [piece of code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to work on - please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Sir, you are absolutely right. That's why  I am putting my code as well....

Comment: part "text/plain" do |p|
      p.body = render_message("email_plain", :message => "text content")
    end

    attachment :content_type => "image/jpeg",
               :body => File.read("an-image.jpg")

    attachment "application/pdf" do |a|
      a.body = generate_your_pdf_here()
    end

    attachment "application/xlsx" do |a|
      a.body = generate_your_excel_here()
    end

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ActionMailer by any chance?

If so, read this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html , especially point 2.3.1 - Adding attachments.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked for a simple send mail but not with attachement. which I need.

Comment: Are you sure you're pointing to the right path where your attachment is?